# MS Header Control - how to update (repaint) only 1 item?

Tags: winapi, header, controls, refresh

We are using the standard Header control from the OS common controls lib. We need to force the control to refresh the area related to only one column header (item). Is there a special WinAPI message for that, or a trick we could use?

Comment: Why, exactly, would you need to do this? What is the harm in redrawing the entire header?

Comment: @CodyGray, we are using the standard OS header in our development of a [flicker-free ActiveX grid control](http://www.10tec.com). We and doing our best to make it totally flicker-free, so the less the drawing - the better ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `HDM_GETITEMRECT` message to get the rectangle for the item in question, then refresh it using the `InvalidateRect` function.

Comment: Excellent, this also works - though requires one more API call :)
But this is a more "proper" way.

Answer (score 0):

We've used the following trick as the column header texts aren't stored directly in the header (VB6 code):

```
Dim tHI As HD_ITEM
tHI.mask = HDI_TEXT
SendMessage m_hWnd, HDM_SETITEM, lCol, tHI
```

In fact, we do not change the item, but the header "thinks" it happened so actually we force the header to redraw the item.

Caution: HDN_ITEMCHANGING is sent in this case, so ignore it when using this trick.